# How can I print logs on Run tab during unit testing on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to print logs when I get the result of Unit Test/Instrumented Test with Run tab on Android Studio.

I tried with `Log.d()`, `Log.wtf()`, etc., `println()` and also Timber Library.

But three of them didn't print any text on Run tab.

I'd like to see the logs with the result altogether, not in separated tab(Logcat)